# Is there a way in lua to do this Parent.Parent.{{VAR}}.child

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

I'm currently working on a Roblox game for a school assignment, so I'm making a basic tycoon game with a function that works like this:

```lua
game.Workspace.Gate.Touched:Connect(function()
    game.Workspace.Path.Transparency = 0
    game.Workspace.Path.CanCollide = true
    game.Workspace.Fence.Transparency = 0
    game.Workspace.Fence.CanCollide = true
end
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to make this function more practical in the long term to make it something like:

```lua
game.Workspace.Gate.Touched:Connect(function({{myVar}})
    game.Workspace.{{myVar}}.Transparency = 0
    game.Workspace.{{myVar}}.CanCollide = true
end
```

I honestly just started Lua today but picked it up very quickly, but I guess there are plenty of things I missed.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes: `Parent.Parent[VAR].child`

Comment: I'd recommend you to use [CollectionService](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/CollectionService).

Answer (score 2):

This

```lua
game.Workspace.Path.Transparency = 0
```

and this

```lua
game["Workspace"]["Path"]["Transparency"] = 0
```

does exactly the same.
You can also mix both:

```lua
game.Workspace["Path"].Transparency = 0
```

The difference is only in syntax. The first only allows you to access keys which are valid identifiers and looks a bit "cleaner". The second allows you to use any variable or constant.

So this code:

```lua
game.Workspace.Gate.Touched:Connect(function(myVar)
        game.Workspace[myVar].Transparency = 0
        game.Workspace[myVar].CanCollide = true
end
```

is completely fine.

Comment: Ah thanks. I would up vote you but it wont let me sorry.